# Scala Enumeration type mismatch

Tags: enums, scala-2.10

I've been working in a scala 2.10.4 environment and I've run into a strange error with coding such as the following:

```
object TestTypes extends Enumeration {
    type TestTypes = Value
    val Test,
        Blah,
        Blah2 = Value
}

def printStuff(v: TestTypes.Value) = {
    println(v)
}


val v = TestTypes(1)
printStuff(v)
```

Where the error I get is the following:

```
<console>:81: error: type mismatch;
 found   : TestTypes.Value
 required: TestTypes.Value
              printStuff(v)
                         ^
```

But I seriously cannot figure out why this error exists. I cannot upgrade the scala version (Although I've checked and this code works in 2.11.7). Does anybody know why this error occurs or better if there's a way around it?

Comment: I have a similar error with scala 1.2.0 environment. I tried to remove the alias line, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Yeah I'm sadly considering converting the enum to Int types for passing to methods even though it's ugly and not fun